# How to add primary key in room database?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room, android-database

I have a sqlite database and i want to change my database to `Room database`.

One of tables has no any primary key and just have two foreign key.

I created the table before room with this query:

```
CREATE TABLE student_performance(
class_id int , 
student_id char(10), 
class_date date , 
absent boolean DEFAULT 0, 
delay boolean DEFAULT 0, 
positive int DEFAULT 0, 
negative int DEFAULT 0, 
quiz float ,
FOREIGN KEY (student_id , class_id) REFERENCES student(student_id , class_id) 
ON DELETE CASCADE 
ON UPDATE CASCADE);
```

Now i define table for room:

```
@Entity(tableName = "performance",
    foreignKeys = {@ForeignKey(
            entity = StudentEntry.class,
            parentColumns = {CLASS_ID, STUDENT_ID},
            childColumns = {CLASS_ID, STUDENT_ID},
            onDelete = CASCADE, onUpdate = CASCADE)})
public class PerformanceEntry {
    .
    .
    .
}
```

But it gives error :

```
error: An entity must have at least 1 field annotated with @PrimaryKey
```

I dont know how can define this table for room database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One does not have to run `CREATE TABLE` SQL, when having `tableName` and `@ColumnInfo` annotations present. Add a primary key `entry_id` (since the `class_id` barely is unique):

```
@Entity(
    tableName = "performance",
    foreignKeys = {
        @ForeignKey(
            entity = StudentEntry.class,
            parentColumns = {CLASS_ID, STUDENT_ID},
            childColumns = {CLASS_ID, STUDENT_ID},
            onDelete = CASCADE,
            onUpdate = CASCADE
       )
   }
)
public class PerformanceEntry  {

    /* Fields */
    @ColumnInfo(name = "entry_id")
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    private int entryId;

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you . I understand what you mean now , If i dont mistake , Either way Room needs a primary key for each table to add, update, and delete operations

Answer (score 1):

Example:

`primaryKeys = {"class_id", "lastName", "class_date", ... , "quiz"})`

In Relational Databases when you don't have any primary key means all of the fields are primary key together.

When you use `ORM` you should usually define an Id attribute for your entities.

Answer (score 1):

Check [the official doc](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#primary-key).

**Just use the `@PrimaryKey` annotation.**

> Each entity must define at least 1 field as a primary key. Even when there is only 1 field, you still need to annotate the field with the [`@PrimaryKey`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/PrimaryKey.html) annotation. Also, if you want Room to assign automatic IDs to entities, you can set the `@PrimaryKey`'s [`autoGenerate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/PrimaryKey.html#autoGenerate()) property. If the entity has a composite primary key, you can use the [`primaryKeys`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Entity.html#primaryKeys()) property of the [`@Entity`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/Entity.html) annotation, as shown in the following code snippet:

Something like:

```
@Entity(...)
public class PerformanceEntry {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int class_id;

    //..

}
```

or

```
@Entity(...)
public class PerformanceEntry {
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)

    //..

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the autoGenerate property

Your annotation should be like this:

@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)